# Determine plot size with grid Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting some data using `plt.scatter()`, and I want to change the size of the plot which is it on, however the only results which come up when you search 'change plot size' are things to do with changing the figure's size, which I am not looking to do.

To visualise my issue, I have a reproducible example where I'm trying to plot 4 points on a 10x10 grid, however the size of the scatter plot is determined by the data not the grid

[image]
[image]

The two graphs above demonstrate my problem, I am trying to plot the four points on the left graph on the 10x10 grid seen on the right graph. I have added in a datapoint at (10, 10) to show this.

My code is currently:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 11, 1))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 11, 1))
plt.grid()
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Which produces the left graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.grid()
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just change the limits of x and y axes:

```
plt.xlim(0,11)
plt.ylim(0,11)
```